# why the parse map data to object jump in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using this code to parse a hash map data to an object in flutter:

```
factory Channel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Channel(
    id: json["id"],
    author: json["author"] == null ? "" : json["author"],
    deleted: json["deleted"] == null ? false : json["deleted"],
    content: json["content"] == null ? "" : json["content"],
    dead: json["dead"] == null ? false : json["dead"],
    poll: json["poll"] == null ? null : json["poll"],
    parent: json["parent"] == null ? null : json["parent"],
    parts: json["parts"] == null
        ? []
        : List<int>.from(json["parts"].map((x) => x)),
    descendants: json["descendants"] == null ? 0 : json["descendants"],
    kids: json["kids"] == null
        ? []
        : List<int>.from(json["kids"].map((x) => x)),
    score: json["score"] == null ? 0 : json["score"],
    pubTime: json["pubTime"] == null ? 0 : json["pubTime"],
    title: json["title"] == null ? "" : json["title"],
    subName: json["subName"] == null?"":json["subName"],
    subUrl: json["subUrl"] == null?"":json["subUrl"],
    isFav: json["isFav"] == null?"":json["isFav"],
    intro: json["intro"] == null?"":json["intro"],
  );
```

when the code runs to this line        `isFav: json["isFav"] == null?"":json["isFav"],` of code, just jump and return nothing, no error output, what should I do to figure out and fix this problem?

[image]

I tried in outer code using try catch like this:

```
static List<Channel> convertTheResult(Response response) {
    if (RestClient.respSuccess(response)) {
      var channelResult = response.data["result"];
      if (channelResult == null) {
        return null;
      }
      var channelListResult = channelResult["list"];
      List<Channel> channels = [];
      channelListResult.forEach((element) {
        try {
          Channel parsedChannel = Channel.fromMap(element);
          if (parsedChannel != null) {
            channels.add(parsedChannel);
          }
        } on Exception catch (e) {
          CruiseLogHandler.logError(CruiseApiError('Channel parsed failed.'), JsonEncoder().convert(response));
        }
      });
      return channels;
    }
  }
```

still not capture any exception clue.

Comment: Can you provide a runnable code sample to reproduce your problem? I don't think the information you provided is not actionable.

Comment: I'd wrap your http methods inside a try catch. Usually its a conversion error that happens silently

Comment: I'll try @James

Comment: Thank you, I finnally find the reson is the isFav is int @James

Answer (score 0):

the `isFav` data type is int,change the code like this:

```
    isFav: json["isFav"] == null ? 0 : json["isFav"],
```